# Choosing an alias from a smartcard

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, smartcard

I am looking for a way to make a choice which alias to use from a smart card. I need the key identified by the alias to sign my pdf document. I'm using the implementation with `WINDOWS-MY` keystore. When there are multiple aliases with their private/public key pairs on the smart card I use:

```
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
```

I get my document signed with the first alias that is in the `WINDOWS-MY` key store. I can list everything on the smart card with:

```
Enumeration enumeration = ks.aliases();
while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
String a = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
System.out.println("alias name: " + a);}
```

and hardcode the alias I want to use by name. Is there however a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got just one smart card type to worry about you could certainly program it this way.

To make it more dynamic/reliable I would first take a look at the accompanying certificate. 
Check for instance if the **key usage** within the certificate indicates that the private key may be used for signing. You could also check other fields, such as the certificate's signature, issuer and expiry date, revocation state etc. Otherwise you may allow for signing with a key that is not supposed to be used for the type of service you are providing.

The person doing the signing may also want to know that it is signing with the right smart card/certificate/private key.